# ASP.NET MVC: DropDownListFor doesn't select any option when rendered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

I have this to populate a drop down list in an ASP.NET MVC view.

C#

```
ViewBag.Employees = new SelectList(
            _employeeRepository.GetAll(), 
            "ID", 
            "LastName",
            employeeToClientContract.EmployeeID);
```

CSHTML

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeID, ViewBag.Employees as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Please select")
```

NOTE: For some reason this works

```
ViewBag.OverridePhysicians = new SelectList(
            _employeeRepository.GetAll().Where(e => e.EmployeeTypes.TypeType == 1), 
            "ID", 
            "LastName",
            employeeToClientContract.OverridePhysicianID);

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OverridePhysicianID, ViewBag.OverridePhysicians as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Please select")
```

Debugging this I can see that the Selected property is set to true when it should be. But when the view is rendered, none of the options in the list is selected.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: The problem wasn't with any of the control configurations. My problem was extra spaces in my URL. All I had to do was call .Trim() to fix the problem.

```
$('#itemsTable').bootstrapTable({

        }).on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
            window.location.href = "/EmployeeToClientContract/Edit?employeeId=" + row[0].toString().trim() + "&clientContractId=" + row[2].toString().trim();
        });
```

Comment: model.EmployeeID contain a value?  The selected field of SelectList is not used and will be ignored, don't even bother with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DropDownListFor` Helper use `model.EmployeeID` value to set selected value in DropdownList. This property has value?

Also, why are facing so much difficults with `SelectList`? Don't you want to populate `ViewBag` like this:

```
ViewBag.Employees = _employeeRepository
.GetAll()
.Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
     Text = x.LastName,
     Value = x.ID.ToString(),
     Selected = employeeToClientContract.EmployeeID == x.ID
});
```

Comment: Yes. The return object to the view is correctly hydrated.

Comment: @kyle This is working solution based on everything you have provided. Please mark this as an answer.